# Is (are) there any crucial gene(s) for the formation of flower in flowering plants?

Tags: genetics, botany, flowering, flowers

I am interested in qualitative (flowers of some plants have petal or sepal, but some plants have not) and quantitative (number of flowers of plants) differences between flowers of different plants.
Formation of flower in flowering plants is under control of which genes?
Which genes are the most important ones in flower development, for example which gene tell the flower that you should have for example 2 stigmas. or which genes tell the plant that you should have 4 flowers or your flowers will not have sepal...
Thank you

Comment: I think this is far too broad (all flowering plants, different features, both initiation and development). You are asking for a textbook. Can you narrow this down?

Comment: I am looking for a brief description

Comment: I think you are looking for the [ABC model of flower development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABC_model_of_flower_development)